# htaccess of front controller seems to block images, JavaScript, and CSS

Tags: .htaccess, url, model-view-controller, mod-rewrite, front-controller

I have a problem regarding my .htaccess file. It is placed in the root folder of my site together with the index.php (my front controller) and the folders regarding CSS, JavaScript, and images. The following is the URL-related content of my .htaccess file

```
# skip existent files
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule index.php - [QSA,L,C]
RewriteRule .* - [QSA,L]

# protect PHP files from the outside
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\.php$
RewriteRule ^.*\.php$ - [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^img/*$
RewriteRule ^img/*$ - [QSA,L]

# refer root to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]

# redirect 404 for non existent files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\..*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\..*$ - [R=404,L]

# adjust the rest of the domains
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I then open the website in the browser, it does not load the respective resources. If I click on "show image source", it immediately refers to the 404 page.

Do you have any idea which part I need to adjust to work around this problem? The root structure looks as follows

```
root
-.htaccess
-/css
-/js
-/img
-index.php
```

Thank you very much in advance! :)

EDIT 10/08/2021:
I figured out that the problem was stemming from other RewriteRules which I put into the last section right before RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA,L], e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^study-programmes/(.*)$ index.php?site=study-programmes&faculty=$1 [L]
```

However, I have several pages where I need specifically named parameter (such as faculty in the example above). What exactly do I need to adjust in order to make it work?

Comment: Try deleting everything and adding each rewrite block back in to debug. Other idea is to put the non-existent files block in the beginning so it's executed first.

Comment: Cheers! I did that and figured out that it seems as if other rewrite rules which I did not post here (e.g. RewriteRule ^study-programmes/(.*)$ index.php?site=study-programmes&faculty=$1 [L]) have blocked the resources for whatever reason...I put those before the RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA,L] in the last block

Comment: How exactly are you referring to those resources in your HTML code? My suspicion is that you probably not took into account, how the base path that relative URLs get resolved against changes, when you introduce a new “folder level” in your main document URL.

Comment: I am referring to index.php only, where the parameter 'site' is used to define the page itself (e.g. contact, imprint, etc.). Several pages (e.g. study-programmes, hence index.php?site=study-programmes) require additionall parameters to then go 'one level deeper', even though I am not referring to an actual folder. The front controller just displays different contents based on whether the additional parameter is given or not

Answer (score 0):

The image matching rules are not written correctly. The `.` is missing from the rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^img/.*$
RewriteRule ^img/.*$ - [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I also suspect there is some other problem. `RewriteRule .* - [QSA,L]` should disable all of the following rewrite rules. `RewriteCond` will only work for the next `RewriteRule` so the second `RewriteRule` in the first section will get executed no matter what and the `L` flag will disable all of the following rules

Comment: Cheers for both of your comments! Have a look at my answer to @okzoomer above—this is what blocked the loading of the resources.